# Spring Cassandra model mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

I have a table as following

```
col1 text,
col2 timestamp,
col3 text,
col4 text,
col5 text,
col6 date,
col7 time,
```

I do not know how to create a bean class for the above table.
So far i have created a bean with following keys. But it does not work

```
@PrimaryKey
String col1;

Date col2;

String col3;

String col4;

String col5;

Date col6;

String col6;
```

Please help me to handle Cassandra datatype such as `timestamp`, `time` and `date` in Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
┌───────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ timestamp │ java.util.Date                         │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ date      │ com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate     │
├───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ time      │ long                                   │
└───────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

<sup>1. [Spring Data for Apache Cassandra - 13.1. Data Mapping and Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-conversion)</sup>
<sup>2. [Java Driver for Apache Cassandra - CQL to Java type mapping](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)</sup>

Comment: Besides these types, you can use other time-related Java types if you use optional codecs: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/custom_codecs/extras/